# Connect to Sql Server 2000 using php + apache

Tags: php, sql-server-2000, lamp

I'm running an Ubuntu 10.04 server with a basic lamp setup.  I'm trying to connect to a sql server 2000 database using php but I have been unsuccessful so far.  I've googled all that I can to no avail.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The mssql extension isn't included in the default PHP package on Ubuntu 10.04.

You have to install it using `apt-get install php5-mssql`.
It's working for me.

Comment: I had somehow missed that.  Would you mind providing an example of your connection string?  Thank  you!

Comment: If you are not using named instances, you can simply use a hostname or ip address (e.g. `mssql_connect('dbserv', 'user', 'password')`).

With named instances, it's `mssql_connect('dbserv\instancename', 'user', 'password)`.

Comment: I tried this but I got a server error.  Am I formatting this wrong?  


    <?php   
    $server = '192.168.1.47,1443';  

    // Connect to MSSQL    
    $link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');    
  
   if (!$link) {   
        die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');    
   }   
   ?>

Comment: I think you have to use 192.168.1.47:1443 on linux. Or just skip the port, since it defaults to 1443 anyway.

Comment: I tried both and they didn't work.  Any advice?  This problem is killing me :)

Comment: Do you get an error message? If not, try mssql_get_last_message() which might return an error message.

Comment: I found this and tried it and received the functions not available message.


if (function_exists('mssql_fetch_row')) {
echo "MSSQL functions are available.<br />\n";
} else {
echo "MSSQL functions are not available.<br />\n";
}
So I am definitely missing something, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this documentation?

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: Yes I have.  And I think I've gone through it properly with no result.  Is there a proverbial checklist I can walk through to make sure I have everything installed correctly?

Comment: I mean I installed freetds and tried using the connection string it provides but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't see anything about mssql on my phpinfo() page.